# Unable to set equation in redhawk's fcalc component

Tags: python, redhawksdr

In REDHAWK IDE (v2.12), I am trying to use `fcalc` component for some math calculations. I tried to follow an example in the doc by putting `math.sin(a+b)+random.random()` in the equation field, but I got the following error:

```
CF.PropertySetPackage.InvalidConfiguration: Failure: . Properties: equation
IDL:CF/PropertySet/InvalidConfiguration:1.0
```

I also tried other math functions, such as `sqrt`. However, none of them worked. It is very hard to add any modules in the import field as well.

Did I do anything wrong while using this fcalc component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the property change listener is not being triggered for the initial property configuration when launched in the IDE sandbox. There are several workarounds:

1. Manually configure the `import` property after launching the component, which will trigger the property change listener. Adding `time` to the list of imports, for example, will then import `math` and `random` as well.
2. Use the Python sandbox instead of the IDE sandbox

   ```
   >>> from ossie.utils import sb
   >>> fcalc = sb.launch('rh.fcalc')
   2019-01-04 11:55:44 WARNING rh_fcalc:176 - NOT overriding global namespace with random from random
   >>> fcalc.equation = 'sin(a+b)+random.random()'
   ```

   The warning is expected and just indicates that you can't use `random()` in the equation without the full namespace `random.random()` because it would conflict with the `random` library.
3. Launch `rh.fcalc` in a waveform in a domain